# Once the page layout changes, are already created records follow the new layout or the Old one?

Tags: page-layout

there is something strange thing happened to me. I have changed the pagelayout for cases. Even  after this , the old cases shows the field that was were in previous page layout .

Moreover, internal comments field is coming up for the Edit layout but not for the detail layout. whenever I edit the records fields comes up , but in details it's not coming . Same page layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page layouts are dynamic and real-time. When you change them, they'll take effect the next time the page is loaded by a user. If you have multiple page layouts, it's possible that you modified the wrong layout. Note that field level security can also affect a layout's rendering, since fields that are not viewable won't appear. Internal Comments will never appear on a detail page. It is a *convenience field* that allows a user to add a comment to the case at the same time while they are editing or closing the case. When a value is put into this field, a new comment will be added to the case comment related list.